# responsive layout issue with rating stars

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, rwd, grid-layout

I have uploaded a image to show what the problem is, as you can see from the image the add to cart button is covering the information. This is on all portrait views. Its also wrong in landscape views. I have been told that its because of the star rating pushing everything down. The site is Magento 1.9.2.1 My website is [here](http://www.timports.co.uk/kiln-dried-logs) . Please could someone give me some advice on how to resolve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line no:502(theme-style.css)
Change into

```
ul.display li .product-image-col .button {
  bottom: 14px;
  left: 22%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 56%;
}
```

Change this

```
ul.display li .product-image-col .button {
    bottom: 0;
    clear: both;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 56%;
}
```

[image]